# Android Studio 1.5 Gradle Experimental : cannot generate JNI stub

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, java-native-interface

As of Android Studio 1.3, it should be possible to automatically generate a JNI stub right after declaring a `native` method without having to use `javah`.

Example here : [image: JNI Auto Stub Generation Example] (from http://ph0b.com/new-android-studio-ndk-support/)

**I can't.**

I am using :

1. `plugin: 'com.android.model.application'` in app `build.gradle` ;
2. `classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.2.1"` in project `build.gradle` inside `dependancies` scope ;
3. `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.5-all.zip` in `gradle-wrapper.properties` ;
4. In Project Structure I am using `Gradle 2.5` as required by Gradle Experimental.

My NDK scope is as followed :

```
android.ndk {
    moduleName = "MyJNILibrary"
    cppFlags += "-std=c++11"
    stl = 'gnustl_shared'
}
```

And finally, the class containing the JNI call :

package modules.jni;

```
public class JniClass {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("MyJNILibrary");
    }

   public static native String getStringFromJNI();
}
```

That's it. What am I doing wrong ?

And I cannot even use javah because it won't find my class file while being in project `src` directory :

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\javah.exe" -d ./jni -classpath
>   C:\android-sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar;...\build\intermediates\classes\debug
>   modules.jni.JniClass

`Error: Could not find class file for 'JniClass'.`

UPDATE 1:

My mistake, in my aforementioned command line, I use `...\` which is wrong because it is supposed to be `..\` so I can use `javah` for the meantime.

Comment: A bit late but I would also like to know how do this again, can't seem to do it either :(